# Reading an image with OpenCV, altering the pixels and returning the new image

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm using Python, OpenCV and Numpy to read a black and white image.
I then iterate over each pixel using numpy.nditer and either change the pixel to 255 (if it is greater than 128), or change it to 0.
Through some testing, I think I have that part right.
What I cannot figure out is how to use cv2.imshow to 'show' the altered image. Currently, it only seems to show the original image.

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    image = cv2.imread('someimage', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    it = np.nditer(image)
    for (x) in it:
        if x > 128:
            x = 255
        else:
            x = 0

    cv2.imshow('image',image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is probably to use the threshold function from opencv. Opencv functions are often faster than numpy functions.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('someimage', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

ret, image = cv2.threshold(image, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

cv2.imshow("Threshold image", image)
cv2.waitKey(-1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Same speed for me, roughly, for a 800x600 random array, but I like the consistency of using the cv function.

Comment: But it's definitely faster if you use the output arg: `cv2.threshold(image, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, image)` instead of `ret, image = cv2.threshold...` (which is why my `where` was faster before I realized that).

Comment: @askewchan Thanks, I did not know that. Is it true for every opencv function having an optional output argument?

Comment: I'm not sure @Hugo, just happened to notice it in the signature for `threshold`. Here it's called `dst`. It's common in numpy where it's called `out`.

Comment: Hugo, I finally got a chance to try this, it is noticeably faster; thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look into the `np.where` function:

```
image[:] = np.where(image > 128, 255, 0)
```

You really shouldn't be looping through arrays unless absolutely necessary:

```
In [16]: %%timeit
   ....: a = np.random.randint(0, 255, (800,600))
   ....: a[:] = np.where(a > 128, 255, 0)
   ....:
10 loops, best of 3: 27.6 ms per loop

In [17]: %%timeit
   ....: image = np.random.randint(0, 255, (800,600))
   ....: it = np.nditer(image, op_flags=['readwrite'])
   ....: for (x) in it:
   ....:     if x > 128:
   ....:         x[...] = 255
   ....:     else:
   ....:         x[...] = 0
   ....:
1 loops, best of 3: 1.26 s per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
it = np.nditer(image, op_flags=['readwrite'])
for (x) in it:
    if x > 128:
        x[...] = 255
    else:
        x[...] = 0
```

From http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html - by default assigning to elements in the iterator will just change their reference, rather than modify the original array. We have to specify the `readwrite` flag, and include the ellipsis.

Comment: michealcurtis, thank you much! This worked for what I was trying to do. I have no idea what the [...] are supposed to be for, I have some reading to do.

Comment: Thank you to everyone else, I appreciate the feedback and the suggestions to have more efficient code.